# java library that uses javafx

Tags: java, javafx

## simple description:

how to make a java library that uses a javafx window (the library has plotting capabilities, is capable to create a popup window) without having a class that extends the `Application` javafx class and how to ship the created application that is using my library as a fatJar?

## full description:

i'm developing a dataframe library because i need a table/dataframe be serializable. and i didnt find any dataframe library for java which implements serializable. my library is almost done. the main logic is working perfectly etc. my library will have plotting functions to plot the table data. i have implemented this functionality trought the ["chart-fx"](https://github.com/fair-acc/chart-fx) library. i have created a starting point class ("class with a static main") to test my library and see if the plotting is working. everything run fine when executed in intellij ide. but when i generate a package (fatJar) in maven and i run the generated jar i get the error: "`java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot resolve 'fa-arrows-alt'`".
the thing that i guess big strange in the implementation of my library is that as i'm developing a library not an application i'm `not following the standard line when creating a javafx application that is to creating a class that extends the Application class of javafx`.
instead i'm using the static method "`Platform.startup("a lambda function with my javafx code here")`".
bellow is the console log when running the generated fatJar with "`-Dprism.verbose=true`" option.

```
jan. 25, 2024 3:55:38 PM com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl startup
WARNING: Unsupported JavaFX configuration: classes were loaded from 'unnamed module @3b192d32'
Prism pipeline init order: d3d sw
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Loading D3D native library ...
        succeeded.
D3DPipelineManager: Created D3D9Ex device
Direct3D initialization succeeded
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.d3d.D3DPipeline
Maximum supported texture size: 16384
Maximum texture size clamped to 4096
OS Information:
        Windows version 10.0 build 19042
D3D Driver Information:
        NVIDIA GeForce GT 710
        \\.\DISPLAY1
        Driver nvldumdx.dll, version 27.21.14.5671
        Pixel Shader version 3.0
        Device : ven_10DE, dev_128B, subsys_118B10DE
        Max Multisamples supported: 4
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot resolve 'fa-arrows-alt'
        at org.kordamp.ikonli.AbstractIkonResolver.resolve(AbstractIkonResolver.java:61)
        at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.IkonResolver.resolve(IkonResolver.java:73)
        at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.setIconLiteral(FontIcon.java:251)
        at org.kordamp.ikonli.javafx.FontIcon.<init>(FontIcon.java:92)
        at io.fair_acc.chartfx.plugins.Zoomer.getZoomInteractorBar(Zoomer.java:421)
        at io.fair_acc.chartfx.plugins.Zoomer.<init>(Zoomer.java:148)
        at io.fair_acc.chartfx.plugins.Zoomer.<init>(Zoomer.java:252)
        at io.fair_acc.chartfx.plugins.Zoomer.<init>(Zoomer.java:243)
        at sst.visualization.chartFxBased.LineChart.lambda$plot$1(LineChart.java:85)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$startup$5(PlatformImpl.java:294)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.invokeAndWait(Application.java:470)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runToolkit(QuantumToolkit.java:377)
        at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.lambda$startup$10(QuantumToolkit.java:290)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.Application.lambda$run$1(Application.java:155)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:185)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
 vsync: true vpipe: true
```

## things that i tried:

1 - run my program with "`--module-path`" and "`--add-modules`". full console command: "`java --module-path C:/javafx-jmods --add-modules javafx.base -jar sst-0.0.1.0-withDependencies.jar`". i got "`Module javafx.base not found`" error same when changing "javafx.base" to another module name.

2 - add the "`javafx-maven-plugin`" to my pom.xml. seems not have effect.

## my thoughts:

i remember that some days ago i have created an javafx application that extends the Application class i that has ran.

## alternative question:

as i feel strange the usage of "`Platform.startup`" so tell me if this is the correct way to creating a javafx plot that is not an application (a generic stuff which create a popup window at screen). because almost everything about javafx is complicated and even more is focused on applications. i'm not sure even about the installation of javafx. i dont wanna do a couse or even read books and waste a month of study to learn something that i have done (plotting my dataframe chart).

Comment: What about using jlink/jpackage instead of a fat JAR?

Comment: the java module system is something new to me, i'm also new on java. is sad to be forced to use the module system (i dont like that).

Comment: if using the module system is required so will each stuff that uses my library to be required to use the system module too? yeah if the module system is the problem i'll have to study a lot of it. i was skipping the module system cause its complexity

Comment: When working with JavaFX, I would generally recommend using modules, yes

Comment: additional information: "i'm using maven build tool and javafx was added trought of maven dependencies".

Comment: The issue in your stack trace is: `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot resolve 'fa-arrows-alt' at org.kordamp.ikonli.AbstractIkonResolver.resolve(AbstractIkonResolver.java:61)`.  That has nothing to do with JavaFX.  That is related your usage of the [ikonli library](https://github.com/kordamp/ikonli) (and no, I don't know how you resolve that).

Comment: [Try](https://kordamp.org/ikonli/)    section 2.3 creating fat jar. I recently ran into the same issue and I think that was the solution for me.

Comment: thanks @Sedj601 and @jwelsea. is true, adding the "`org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer`" solved my problem. now the "fatJar" is running. i had to change my "transformers" section of the pom.xml to:
```
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
        <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
         <mainClass>${mainClass}</mainClass>
        </transformer>
```
and now i can run my application as normal fatJar or even with a double click.

Comment: ok i have studied a bit java modules and i tried to find what was happening. so i have compared the two generated fatJar files. the fatJar with the transformer and working and the one that was not working. using the [WinMerge](https://winmerge.org/) program i found the differences were in the services (META-INF/services) directory. so probably when shading (generating fatJar) one of the service was replaced by another library. and when using the maven "ServicesResoureTransformer" when there a services which would replace another one their contents are concatenated. fixing my problem of missing

Comment: @Basil I did not downvote, but I could see people downvoting for lack of a [mre].

Comment: @Lucas Figuring out what was wrong with your setup could have been guessed from the information you provided, especially if one is familiar with the fact that ikonli uses the service-provider mechanism. However, a [mre] (including an example POM) would have made it easier to spot the problem. Since your figured out the solution you should consider writing your own answer. Though I'm pretty sure there is a duplicate out there for your problem.

Comment: Using `Platform::startup` is a perfectly acceptable alternative to using `Application::launch`, particularly if you know what you're doing. Since you're not creating a full-blown GUI application, but rather just using JavaFX to include a visualize-data feature, which may or may not be utilized by consumers of your "dataframe library", it makes sense to use `startup` if and when needed.

Comment: @BasilBourque I downvoted because I found the question confusing and the actual issue unrelated to the title.  The text of the question brings up unrelated issues, obfuscating the real issue.  The title is "java library that uses javafx", which isn't a question. The actual issue is: How to package software that uses ikonli as an executable fat jar file?  This has a specific solution as documented in the ikonli library documentation.  An alternative question is indicative of a lack of focus.  The downvote was just my opinion, obviously differing opinions are valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using javafx to a non application, can be used the "Platform.startup" static method. and you can just add the maven dependencies to you pom without installing the .jmods of javafx or work with the java module system.

Specifically for the library "[ikonli](https://github.com/kordamp/ikonli)" which is used by the "[chart-fx](https://github.com/fair-acc/chart-fx)" library cause a issue about replacing dependency services when generating a fatJar ("files located in META-INF/services of a jar"). to avoid replacing the service files and merge them instead is required to add a specific [maven resource transformer](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html) the "[`ServiceResourceTransformer`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#ServicesResourceTransformer)" that will merge the services content when needed.

things learned:

1. is not required to use the modular system to work with javaFX or have the javaFX sdk or jmods.
2. a fatJar may not be the safest way to ship java applications because there always a risk of conflicts between resources and files.

thanks to:
@Sedj601 and @jwelsea and @Slaw for help.